# Lower Login button to very bottom of my web app

Tags: html, css, node.js, vue.js

I was wondering how do I position my Login button at the bottom centre of the screen and have the image displayed over it? I want this to be essentially the homepage. My image is not displaying either for some reason.

Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <img alt="Sportly logo" src="~@/assets/sportly.png">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"
                @click="signIn">

               <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                    Sign In with Twitter
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        signIn () {
            this.$store.dispatch('signIn')
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
h3 {
    font-weight: 700;

}
button {
    background-color: #1dcaff;
    border: 1px solid  #1dcaff;


}
div button:hover {
    background-color: #00aced;
    border: 1px solid  #00aced;

}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: About the image not loading, you should post on a different question with more details.

Comment: have my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sign in button to be on top of an image, it would be easier to set a div with a background image and put the button on top of that. Your question is worded so that the image goes over the button, which is probably not what you want.

CSS

```
.mybackground {
background-image: url('yourimage.jpg');
}
```

HTML (get rid of img tag)

```
<div class="container-fluid mybackground">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"
                @click="signIn">

               <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                    Sign In with Twitter
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `position: fixed` + `bottom: XXpx` to send the div to the bottom of the page, `width: 100%` + `margin: 0 auto` + `text-align: center` to center the elements, and `position: relative` + `z-index: 1` to overlap the login button and the image. Here are the results:

```css
h3 {
  font-weight: 700;
}
button {
  background-color: #1dcaff;
  border: 1px solid  #1dcaff;
}
div button:hover {
  background-color: #00aced;
  border: 1px solid  #00aced;
}
.loginarea {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px; /* Distance from window bottom */
  width: 100%;
}
.loginarea .center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px; /* Width of logo */
}
.loginarea .logo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.loginarea .row {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px; /* Width of logo */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid loginarea">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 logindiv">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-primary"
          @click="signIn">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
          Sign In with Twitter
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img class="logo" alt="Sportly logo" src="http://placekitten.com/200/100">
  </div>
</div>
```